# C++, Getting, adding, and dividing percentiles

Tags: c++, percentile

I'm very new to c++. I need help on how to:

1. get percentiles (which I think I'm doing right..?, and
2. how to add them to another number.

Here is part of my code, I'm not even sure if I'm including the right headers. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    double total, tipTotal, taxTotal, cost, tax, tip;
    cost = 44, 50;
    tax = 100 - 93.25;
    tip = 100 - 85;

    total = cost + tax + tip;

    tipTotal = cost + tax + tip;

    taxTotal = cost + tax;

    // other code
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, I probably see mistake in your code - after `cost = 44,50;` cost have value `50.`, you probably want `cost = 44.50;` (dot instead of comma)

Comment: To be fair, I don't think your problem is so much with C++, as it is with basic math.

Comment: You do not use any function from iostream nor iomanip, so both of them are unnecessary. What exactly is your problem? What are you trying to do? I mean, "get percentiles": you are supposed to get them from the keyboard? or "how to add them": Not sure if mathematically that is possible, but with C++ you did it correctly.

Comment: Please, when you are a beginner in C++, take the habit to compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. with `g++ -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g.  `gdb`). Knowing how to use the debugger is an essential skill, both for newbies and experts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think you have a typo.
I think you meant to say 44.50 (with a decimal point).
    cost = 44.50;
Because the comma is a valid operator, the compiler does not catch this as an error.

Second, C++ does not handle percentages, so you have to specify percentages as a decimal value.
So 15% is not 15.0 but 0.15.
So your code should say
    tax = 1.00 - 0.9325;
    tip = 1.00 - 0.85;